# Pandas: Delete row based on a condition of more than one column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a DataFrame "df" with three columns named: "Particle", "Frequency1", "Frequency2" and a lot of rows.

I want to delete the rows where Frequency1 and Frequency2 are simoustaneously equal to 0.

What is the sintax for doing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can also use: `df = (df[df.Frequency1 == 0] & df[df.Frequency2 == 0])`.

This will delete the row which has 0 in both columns of 'Frequency1`and`Frequency2`.

Comment: Thank you @Jeru . It works perfectly

Comment: @Laura You can also use: `df[['Frequency1', 'Frequency2']].corr()`. And if the resulting matrix has any values with 1, you can delete the corresponding row. But always use this *only if* the values in `Frequency1` and `Frequency2` are equal to 0. They must not be equal to  each other. This is another more complicated way of doing it. Just thought of sharing it !!!